# What happens when the Leomund's Tiny Hut spell intersects solid objects, like the ends of a large wagon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Unlike in previous editions, in 5e Leomund’s Tiny Hut makes a hemisphere, has been ruled to have a floor, and protects vs attacks — so I’m not sure what happens when the hemisphere intersects solid objects, like the ends of a large wagon, when cast.

Assuming the wagon is large enough for both ends to stick out, would the hemisphere pass through its ends and lock the wagon in place, leaving parts of it exposed and vulnerable to attack, or would the spell just fail?

Answer (score 3):

It will not penetrate the wagon.

The PHB pg.204 talks about areas of effect:

> A spell's effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin.
>   If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a
>   location within the area of effect, that location isn't included in
>   the spell's area.

The point of origin is **yourself** and it is a **ten-foot hemisphere**, so the area that becomes the hut is from **you**, out to a **radius of ten feet**, **constrained by the walls of the wagon**

*What the spell doesn't specify is whether this reduced area would also reduce the number of creatures you can contain in it. Since it is magic and not specified, I would think it does not reduce the internal space. **However, that is purely my opinion/interpretation. I would strongly suggest asking your DM for a ruling on it as it is rather vague.***

Comment: To assume a clear LOS from the caster is required would almost certainly preclude all other creatures standing in that space.  A clear LOS to all parts of the hemisphere must not be required since the spell is meant for those creatures to be there when cast.  My opinion was, like before when a sphere, the hemisphere just goes around anything in its way, near a cliff, on a non level surface, or through obstructions.  Anything outside is vulnerable and can't come in, anything inside protected and can go out. But I was wondering if some official ruling was made on it.

Comment: @JRTStarlight I agree with your interpretation but to my knowledge, there is no official ruling. I would suggest maybe posing the question on twitter for Crawford?